# Find groups of files that end with the same 17 characters

Tags: bash, shell

I'm grabbing files that have a unique and common pattern. I'm trying to match on the common. Currently trying with bash. I can use python or whatever.

```
file1_02_01_2021_002244.mp4
file2_02_01_2021_002244.mp4
file3_02_01_2021_002244.mp4
# _02_01_2021_002244.mp4 should be the 'match all files that contain this string'

file1_03_01_2021_092200.mp4
file2_03_01_2021_092200.mp4
file3_03_01_2021_092200.mp4
# _03_01_2021_092200.mp4 is the match
...    
file201_01_01_2022_112230.mp4
file202_01_01_2022_112230.mp4
file203_01_01_2022_112230.mp4
# _01_01_2022_112230.mp4 is the match
```

the goal is to find all that are matching from the very end of the file back to the first uniq character, then move them into a folder. The actionable part will be easy. I just need help with the matching.

```
find -type f $("all that match the same last 17 characters of the file name"); do
    do things
done
```

this is my example directory:

```
total 28480
drwxr-xr-x  2 user  user    64B Feb 24 10:49 dir1
drwxr-xr-x  2 user  user    64B Feb 24 10:49 dir2
-rw-r--r--  2 user  user   6.8M Feb 24 08:59 file1_02_01_2021_002244.mp4
-rw-r--r--  2 user  user   468K Feb 24 09:06 file1_03_01_2021_092200.mp4
-rw-r--r--  2 user  user   4.5M Feb 24 08:59 file2_02_01_2021_002244.mp4
-rw-r--r--  2 user  user   665K Feb 24 09:06 file2_03_01_2021_092200.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 user  user     0B Feb 24 10:49 otherfile1
-rw-r--r--  1 user  user     0B Feb 24 10:49 otherfile2
```

I've got it to work with suggestions from the answer marked as correct. They python method probably could work better (especially with the file names that have spaces in them) but I'm not proficient with python enough to make it do everything I want. the script in full is found below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
# this is my solution
# create array with patterns
aPATTERN=($(find . -type f -name "*.mp4" | sed 's/^[^_]*//'|sort -u ))

# iterate through all patterns, do things
for each in ${aPATTERN[@]}; do
        # create a temp working directory for files that match the pattern
        vDIR=`gmktemp -d -p $(pwd)`
        # create array of all files found matching the pattern
        aFIND+=(`find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname \*$each`)
        # move all files that match the match to the working temp directory
        for file in ${aFIND[@]}; do
                mv -iv $file $vDIR
        done
        # reset the found files array, get ready for next pattern
        aFIND=()
done
```

Comment: Is the pattern at the end of the file always the same length ?

Comment: @Cubix48 , yeah they are

Comment: Bascically, I would create an associative array, where the key is the last 17 characters of a file, and the value is the list (array) of all files having this ending. This groups your files based on the name endings. Since associative arrays in bash can't have arrays as values, I would not write this in bash. It is possible, but tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play with this

first get all pattern sorted and uniq

```
find ./data -type f -name "*.mp4" | sed 's/^[^_]*//'|sort -u
```

or with regex

```
find ./data -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9]\{6\}\.mp4$'| sed 's/^[^_]*//'|sort -u
```

then iterate the the pattern via while loop to find files for every pattern

```
while read pattern
do
   # find and exec
   find ./data -type f -name "*$pattern" -exec mv {} /to/whatever/you/want/ \;
   #or find and xargs
   find ./data -type f -name "*$pattern" | xargs -I {} mv {} /to/whaterver/you/want/
done < <(find ./data -type f -name "*.mp4" | sed 's/^[^_]*//'|sort -u)
```

Comment: A modified version of your insight helped me solve my problems. I'll update with the solution shortly

Answer (score 3):

In python:

```
import os

os.chdir("folder_path")

data = {}
data = [[file[-22:], file] for file in os.listdir()]

output = {}
for pattern, filename in data:
    output.setdefault(pattern, []).append(filename)
print(output)
```

This will create a dict associating each file with the corresponding pattern.

---

**Output:**

```
{
    '_03_01_2021_092200.mp4': ['file1_03_01_2021_092200.mp4', 'file3_03_01_2021_092200.mp4', 'file2_03_01_2021_092200.mp4'], 
    '_01_01_2022_112230.mp4': ['file202_01_01_2022_112230.mp4', 'file201_01_01_2022_112230.mp4', 'file203_01_01_2022_112230.mp4'], 
    '_02_01_2021_002244.mp4': ['file1_02_01_2021_002244.mp4', 'file2_02_01_2021_002244.mp4', 'file3_02_01_2021_002244.mp4']
}
```

Comment: This is good, I'll practice with this more but I found that I was also grabbing files and directories that didn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach this, including writing a bash script, but if it were me, I'd take the quick and easy road.  Use grep and read:

```
PATTERN=_02_01_2021_002244.mp4
find . -name '*.mp4' | grep $PATTERN; while read -t 1 A; do echo $A; done
```

There are probably better ways that I haven't thought of but this gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" == *_+([0-9])_+([0-9])_+([0-9])_+([0-9])\.mp4 ]]
    then
        echo "MATCH: $line"
    else
        echo "no match: $line"
    fi
done < <(/bin/ls -c1)
```

Remember that is uses globbing, not regex when you build your pattern.

That is why I did not use `[0-9]{2}` to match 2 digits, `{}` does not do that in globbing, like it does in regex.

---

To use regex, use:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ $(echo "$line" | grep -cE '*_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{6}\.mp4') -ne 0 ]]
    then
        echo "MATCH: $line"
    else
        echo "no match: $line"
    fi
done < <(/bin/ls -c1)
```

This is a more precise match since you can specify how many digits to accept in each sub-pattern.